# Hide Row if woocommerce product attribute is selected

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, show-hide, product-variations

I am trying to hide a row depending on whether the product attribute is selected or not.

I have tried to create a new script inside the child theme like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("a.nasa-attr-ux.nasa-attr-ux-image.nasa-attr-ux-sin-logo.nasa-attr-ux-2").click(function(e) { 
        $(".wcuf_upload_fields_row_element").show();
        $(".wcuf_upload_fields_row_element").hide();
    });

    $("a.nasa-attr-ux.nasa-attr-ux-image.nasa-attr-ux-con-logo.nasa-attr-ux-1").click(function(e) { 
        $(".wcuf_upload_fields_row_element").show();
        $(".wcuf_upload_fields_row_element").hide();
    });
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMAyb.png)

enqueue script in function.php

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles', 998);

function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('elessi-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('elessi-child-style', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
}
```

Comment: You need to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead of `get_template_directory_uri()`. `get_template...` looks in the PARENT theme, `get_stylesheet...` looks in the CHILD theme directory

Comment: You always show than hide... ????

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers.
At the end I changed my mind with a plugin that solved what I was looking for.
I really appreciate your help

Comment: Can you share the solution/plugin you settled on? I am looking to do something similar.